# Linux regex file move

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-management, file-transfer, regex

Im trying to move files into subfolders based on a regular expression. For example im trying to move tv shows into the correct show and season folder. All files follow the pattern "Show Name.S00E00.episode title.avi".

I've looked at mmv and rename but can't seem to find any helpful examples.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Edit: I forgot to mention the folder structure is

```
./
   Unsorted video files 
   Show Name/
      Season 1/
           Video Files Sorted
      Season 2/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the *bash* shell:

```
for file in *.avi; do
    # use perl to transform the file name; could use 'sed -r' too
    new_path=$(perl -pe 's|^(.+?)\.S0*(\d+)E0*(\d+)\.(.+)\.(\w+)$|$1/Season $2/Episode $3 - $4.$5|' <<< "$file")
    # create directories if needed
    mkdir -p "${new_path%/*}"
    # move the file
    mv -vn "$file" "$new_path"
done
```

In this regexp example (`s|...|...|`):

- `$1` is the show name (everything up to "`.S<num>E<num>`");
- `$2` and `$3` are season/episode numbers;
- `$4` is the episode title (everything up to the final "`.`");
- `$5` is the file extension.

If you want to keep leading zeroes in season/episode numbers, replace `S0*` and `E0*` with just `S` and `E`. If you want to process other file types, adjust `*.avi` in the first line.

---

Debian and Ubuntu come with a Perl-based `prename` script (aka `perl-rename`) which could be used for this – it creates directories automatically starting with v1.8, so just use:

```
prename 'the above regexp' *.avi
```

Comment: Can you explain why (.+?) for season name, why not just (.+)

Comment: @bbaja42 `.+?` is non-greedy, meaning it will match as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use only bash commands all the way (if all your files really follow the structure you've provided):

```
for episode in *avi ; do
  ### cut $episode into fields, separated by "." and assign the first such field to $showname
  ### assign the second and third character of the second field to $season
  showname=`echo $episode | cut -d "." -f1`
  season=`echo $episode | cut -d "." -f2 | cut -c 2,3`
  ### create directory only if not already created
  mkdir -p $showname/$season
  ### move the file
  mv $episode $showname/$season/
done
```